# on Jquery template how do i set css class dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using asp.net web api project and using jquery template in that.

```
in ready
$('a').click(function () {
            debugger;
            // remove the selected class from all anchors
            $('.row a').removeClass('selected');

            // Add the selected class to the currently clicked anchor
             $(this).addClass('selected');            
        });

<div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <!-- Added dynamic data from script GroupTypeTemplate -->              
            </div>
</div>
<script id="GroupTypeTemplate" type="text/html">
                <nav id="options" class="work-nav">
                    <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">                                            
                         <li>                            
 <a onclick="getGroupById('${Id}')"  data-option-value="*">${TypeName}</a>
                         </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>                 
                </script>
```

> I want to set that `class` attribute dynamically as per which menu is currently active

But how to check which `id` is currently `active` accordingly I can set `class="selected"`

What is the syntax in jquery template ?

Comment: check which menu is active and change class accordingly

Comment: sorry to ask you but i'm new to jquery template where and what is the syntax to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get script to work on dynamically added content you need to put the event on the document like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    //remove, add here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this will put the selected attr only to the `a` that was clicked.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("a").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Is your `<li><a></a><li>` generated dinamically?
try to put this inside `$(document).ready(function(){ PUTHERE  });`

Comment: then try to use `$("a").on('click', function(){ $("a").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected"); 
});` instead.